# Почему перестала работать oAuth через Яндекс?

Tags: php, авторизация, oauth, яндекс-id

На моем сайте, помимо остальных, есть авторизация через Яндекс. Работала исправно пару лет, а недели полторы-две назад внезапно перестала работать. Как выяснилось, проблема в том, что при обращении к адресу *https://api-yaru.yandex.ru/me/* возвращается код 403. Может быть, кто-то в курсе, у них что-то поменялось?

На всякий случай поясню, как именно я работаю с API:

1. Отправляю пользователя на *https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE&display=popup*
2. Отправляю POST-запрос на *https://oauth.yandex.ru/token* с полями grant_type, code, client_id и client_secret. Здесь получаю токен, и токен приходит без ошибок:

   ```
   {
     ["token_type"]=>  
     string(6) "bearer"  
     ["access_token"]=>  
     string(32) "12345678901234567890123456789012"  
     ["expires_in"]=>  
     int(31536000)  
   }
   ```
3. Отправляю GET-запрос на *https://api-yaru.yandex.ru/me/* с заголовками:

   ```
   curl\_setopt($ch, CURLOPT\_HTTPHEADER, array(    
          "Authorization: OAuth ".$token,  
          "Content-Type: application/x-yaru+xml; type=person"  
    ));
   ```

И вот здесь как раз получаю 403 вместо ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Оказалось, необходимо использовать другой адрес: `https://login.yandex.ru/info?[format=json | xml][& oauth_token=<OAuth-токен>]`. В связи с закрытием сервиса ya.ru прежний не работает. Описание находится [здесь](http://api.yandex.ru/login/doc/dg/reference/request.xml).